# How to change the marker and draw a line between dots in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have this code that I am trying to plot:

```
battery_aH=55;
hour_of_battery_work=12;
one_battery_price=147.96;
system_amper=1;
while system_amper<20
    discharge_battery=1;
    [num_of_battery]=num_of_battery1(system_amper,hour_of_battery_work,battery_aH,discharge_battery);
    [total_price]=total_price1(one_battery_price,num_of_battery);
    plot(total_price,system_amper,'markersize', 30,)
    system_amper=system_amper+1;
end
xlabel('price(€)','fontname','times','fontsize',16);
ylabel('Energy of the system[aH]','fontname','times','fontsize',16);

hold off
```

The thing is that when I run this code I am getting small dots.
Can I change the type of mark through the code (not the size)? Can I draw a line between these dots through the code and after it make the dots disappear?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any [`line` properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html) as parameter/value arguments to `plot`. In your case, you should be able to specify the `Marker`, `MarkerSize`, and `LineStyle` properties

```
plot(total_price, system_amper, 'Marker', '*', 'MarkerSize', 30, 'LineStyle', '-')
```

Alternately, you can store the graphics handle to the `line` object produced by `plot` and use `set` to modify the properties

```
h = plot(total_price, system_amper);
set(h, 'Marker', '*', 'MarkerSize', 30, 'LineStyle', '-')
```

Comment: you solve my proble with the marker type! do you know how can i drow a line between these dots through the plot code and after it make the dots disapper with the while loop?

Comment: @RonPotashnik It depends. What are `num_of_battery1` and `total_price1`?

Answer (score 0):

You are plotting the points one-by-one in the 'while' loop. That's why they are not connected together.

What you want to do is to store all the points in an array and then plot them all at once. Then you can change the line and mark specs using [plot options](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html).